# POSTGRESQL: update jsonb if key:value doesn't exsits

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I want to update a jsonb column in table (sample):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_1 AS
SELECT 1 as id,'{"foo":1,"bar":2,"foo_bar":3}'::jsonb as jb_value;
```

in a way that this update:

```
UPDATE tmp_1 
   SET jb_value = jb_value || '{"foo_bar":4, "foo_foo_bar":4}'
 WHERE id = 1;
```

would return something similar to :

```
Result:
{"foo":1,"bar":2,"foo_bar":[3,4],"foo_foo_bar":4}
```

`||` operator is not working for me, because according do [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

> Note: The || operator concatenates two JSON objects by generating an
> object containing the union of their keys, taking the second object's
> value when there are duplicate keys. All other cases produce a JSON
> array: first, any non-array input is converted into a single-element
> array, and then the two arrays are concatenated. It does not operate
> recursively; only the top-level array or object structure is merged.

and this would return replaced value for key `"foo_bar"`, ***which I don't want***:

```
Result:
{"foo":1,"bar":2,"foo_bar":4,"foo_foo_bar":4}
```

I also took `jsonb_insert` and `jsonb_set` under considaration, but I won't know path to the key that I want to update or insert.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: for `"foo_bar":4` and `"foo_bar":[3,4]` key value pair is different first is integer type and second arraytype

Comment: thats why i said "would return something similar " ;) so it might transformed to : {"foo":[1],"bar":[2],"foo_bar":[3,4],"foo_foo_bar":[4]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg( COALESCE(a.key, b.key)
                       , CASE
                             WHEN a.key IS NULL THEN b.value
                             WHEN b.key IS NULL THEN a.value
                             ELSE '[]' :: jsonb || a.value || b.value
                         END
                       )
  FROM jsonb_each('{"foo":1,"bar":2,"foo_bar":3}'::jsonb) AS a
  FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_each('{"foo_bar":4, "foo_foo_bar":4}' :: jsonb) AS b
     ON a.key = b.key
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/84825

You can insert this query into your UPDATE statement.

Comment: thanks @Edouard H. for answer, but I have one problem, when I already have an array in values like this: `FROM jsonb_each('{"foo":1,"bar":2,"foo_bar":[3,5]}'::jsonb) AS a
  FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_each('{"foo_bar":4, "foo_foo_bar":4}' :: jsonb) AS b
     ON a.key = b.key;` i get nested array: `{"foo":1,"bar":2,"foo_bar":[[3,5],4],"foo_foo_bar":4}` any quick fix for this?

Comment: @w8forw8 - Answer updated according to your last comment.